# Add new device for an existing tester on Crashlytics

Tags: ios, testflight, crashlytics

How can I add a new UDID in Crashlytics for an existing tester? The UDID is on the distribution profile but because it's not listed in Crashlytics the user cannot open the app

Comment: http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/370220-why-do-i-see-a-yellow-icon-next-to-a-tester

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to open the link in the invite emails on the new device. The original invite will say "Let Me In" and new build emails will say "Check It Out". Then it'll take you to the page where you can register your new device.

After the device is registered with Crashlytics you should be able to do open the app, seeing that your UDID is already in the provisioning profile.

Answer (score 25):

I didn't know this about using Fabric. I thought you just enter an email address and the tester can install your app but that ONLY works for **enterprise** Apple Dev Accounts. If you have a personal account, how you get your app on a new tester's device is:

1) Archive/distribute your app, add their email to the tester list in crashlytics. They get an email to register.

2) Then you (as the distributer) will receive an email that says they registered and it has their device UDID in it.

3) You need to then go to the app dev website and add this UDID to your device list.

4) Then you need to go to your Xcode preferences and refresh your dev account profile to make sure it's aware of the new device ids (Xcode/ Preferences/Accounts/ Download Manual Profiles).

5) Then you need to re-archive/re-distribute the app again.

On this second email, they can finally install the app.

Comment: There is no API that expose UDID now I guess? You have to add UDID before and then invite them I think thats the safest way now!!

Comment: How to automate this UDID proccess? Fastlane?

Comment: What do you mean by "refresh your dev account profile"? Thanks.

Comment: @MuratYasar Updated the answer with the details, I am not sure if this step is required anymore but it doesn't hurt.

Comment: There is no need to re-archive anymore. After downloading the new provisioning profile with the added UDID, Fabric app let's you click in the "Try Again" button to go ahead and distribute.

Answer (score 7):

I've also had a similar problem.

It took some time but I realized that Crashyltics wasn't using the provisioning profile I was expecting. I had to change my build settings for the Provisioning Profile to not use the Automatic setting but to use my Ad Hoc Profile.

Comment: We had this happen too.  Thanks.

Comment: Fabric needs to add this to their documentation!

Answer (score 6):

Here is a through guide for this:
https://docs.fabric.io/ios/beta/introduction.html

Answer (score 3):

Hemal from Crashlytics here. Once you added the UDID in the provisioning profile, did you redistribute the app again? Also, be sure to double check that the updated provisioning profile is the selected profile of choice in Xcode (and shows up in the top of the Mac app when you build). This way, the latest distribution will pick the most up to date permissions!

Comment: I did distribute the app again but in the Crashlytics dashboard only one of the devices for this tester appears. I have the option to "Revoke access" for that particular device but I can't find any way to add a new device

Comment: I bloody can't figure out how to add device either. Crashlytics site shows bloody dashboard.

Comment: What is missing and not at all visible without looking behind tools is that the Developer's Cert needs to be re-generated.  The Cert is in Keychain and if you are like me and use your Developer account for multiple clients (i.e., been invited to develop under their provisioning), you can expand the Certs in the keychain to identify the Cert for the active client.  You can remove the unneeded ones or simply generate new on the Apple Portal.  THEN ... when you build and distribute on Fabric Beta, you will see the new UDIDs that your and your client have created together.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and I ended up having to go into XCode > Preferences > Accounts > [my dev team], and I manually right clicked on each profile and hit "move to trash".  I then emptied the trash, cleaned (cmd+shift+k), cleaned build folder (cmd+alt+shift+K), deleted DerivedData (google this one), restarted my OS, and finally downloaded all provisioning profiles using the "Download All" button in the same place in XCode after restarting and it worked :)

(not all of these steps might be necessary, but just to be safe...)

Answer (score 0):

If you distribute your app internally with enterprise signing, adding a new device can be tricky, especially if it's a test device that you don't want to setup your email/password manager on. What I've done is open the original invite link from email on my laptop and it will say to open on your device to start testing. (I used an email from months ago, so they don't seem to expire.) From this page, you can AirDrop the link to your new testing device. In the past, I've manually typed the invite link and this is much, much easier.